# snprintf segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, printf

I am trying to understand char pointers in C.
Basically what I am doing is declaring a char* pointer main and passing by reference in another function and modifying there. Now, I want to print the value of the char in the main, which gives me the segmentation fault. But if I print the value in the called function it prints fine.

Also, when I try to do snprintf on char pointer within main, again I get segmentation fault but not  in the called function.

I searched and try to understand the chars and pointers but not able to debug this.

Below is the code with comments:

```
#include<stdio.h>



int main(void)
{
    char *a;
    int ret;
    /* Below line gives Segmentation Fault. */
//  snprintf(a,10,"%s","Hello");
    /* Below line prints '(null)'.OK */
    printf("Before Function Call: %s\n",a); 
    ret = func(&a);
    /* Below line prints count of characters returned from func .OK */
    printf("Characters written : %d\n",ret);
    /* Below line gives Segmentation Fault. */
    printf("After Function Call: %s\n",a);
    return 1;
}

int func(char *b)
{
    int ret = 0;
    /* Below line prints blank. Why? Above it prints '(null)'*/
    printf("    In func-> Before operation: %s\n",b);
    ret = snprintf(b,10,"%s",", World");
    /* Below line prints ' World'. OK */
    printf("    In func-> After operation: %s\n",b);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `char *a;` If you want to use `a`, you need to allocate memory. It depends if you use c or c++ how you allocate memory.

Comment: `&a` is not a `char *`, it's a `char **`.

Comment: "*and modifying there*" The code you show does not modify `b` nor `a`, not directly nor indirectly. The code not even ever assigns a value to `a` or `b`.

Comment: Lots of UB. Bad start to coding in C. Have to be careful from now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go through the functions line by line.

```
char *a;
```

Here you declare a pointer which so far points to nowhere.

```
/* Below line gives Segmentation Fault. */
//  snprintf(a,10,"%s","Hello");
```

Of course it does. As `a` points to "nowhere" or "anywhere", this is undefined behaviour. You should first allocate memory by one or other way and let `a` point there. Then you can use it as you describe.

```
ret = func(&a);
```

Here you pass `a`'s *address* to `func()` - which is ok.

```
/* Below line gives Segmentation Fault. */
printf("After Function Call: %s\n",a);
```

`a` was changed, is not a null pointer any longer as it was above, but points to a destination where nothing can be read of. Undefined behaviour again.

```
return 1;
```

That means failure. Better `return 0` as that would mean success.

```
int func(char *b)
```

Stop. Above you passed `&a` to func. As `a` is a `char *`, `&a` would be a `char **`. B but `func` accepts a `char *`. So there is a discrepancy which leads to errors.

```
/* Below line prints blank. Why? Above it prints '(null)'*/
printf("    In func-> Before operation: %s\n",b);
```

Because above you print `a`, here however you print `b` which is `&a`.

```
ret = snprintf(b,10,"%s",", World");
```

Here you write something to where `b` points, and that is `a` from `main()`. `a` is a pointer, which has size 4 on 32 bit systems and size 8 on 64 bit systems. And should not be abused for storing strings.

```
printf("    In func-> After operation: %s\n",b);
```

This is by chance; you have undefined behaviour again and are likely disturbing the caller's stack frame.

Let's improve your code a bit:

```
// prototype - make the function known to main() so that the right calling convention is used
int func(char *b);

int main(void)
{
    char *a = malloc(100); // should be adjusted depending on the needs...
    int ret;
    /* Below line no longer gives Segmentation Fault now. */
    snprintf(a,10,"%s","Hello");
    printf("Before Function Call: %s\n",a); 
    ret = func(a);
    /* Below line prints count of characters returned from func .OK */
    printf("Characters written : %d\n",ret);
    printf("After Function Call: %s\n",a);
    free(a); // as we alloc'ed it...
    return 0; // as we didn't notice anything going wrong...
}

int func(char *b)
{
    int ret;
    printf("    In func-> Before operation: %s\n",b);
    // Here is the qustion: do we want to append or to overwrite?
    char * b_append = b + strlen(b);
    ret = snprintf(b_append,10,"%s",", World");
    printf("    In func-> After operation: %s\n",b);
    printf("    In func-> We appended %s\n",b_append);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `return 0;` should be there in `main ` .

Comment: @ameyCU: Why? `main()` returns `int`, so `1` is fine, as well as `42` would be.

Comment: @glglgl Thanks for improving the code. When I declared char a[20], it was fine. But was getting different behaviours in both functions when declared as char *. So, what I understand from the comments is that even if values were getting printed in func() it is undefined behaviour and may change on different systems. Is that right?

Comment: @alk yes , I just pointed as it is used more often . No worries !!

Comment: @ameyCU is right - we didn't notice anything going wrong, so we should indicate success.

Comment: @user3275095 UB means *anything* can happen. Program working right, program behaving unexpectedly and program crashing.

Comment: @glglgl What I was getting was lots of UB. I didn't declared the function so at run time &a was also accepted and the values were also getting printed. Lesson: always allocate memory and ofcourse deallocate after use. And remain disciplined while coding in C. :) I hope I got it right.

Comment: Not too much dicipline is the way to success. However, please very well note: "not too much" implies at least "some" ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `a` like this:

```
char a[10];
```

Currently you are passing an uninitialized pointer to snprintf, so you get undefined behavior when snprintf writes to it.

Comment: Thanks. This way it was working but the way I posted was giving different behaviour in both functions. That was the confusion. Now I understand from the comments that it is Undefined behaviour even if values were getting printed in func(). They may not always print. Am I right?

Comment: Yep, sometimes undefined behavior works correctly for you, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
int func(char *b)
             ^requires char pointer
```

What you are passing is

```
ret = func(&a);
            ^This is of type char **
```

Comment: I am trying to understand pointers. So as I understand Char *b is a pointer variable and by using & we fetch the address , which is expected by a pointer variable. Something in examples I saw: int a =5; int *p = &a;

Comment: @user3275095 Yes. `p` now points to `a`'s location. By doing `*p = 12`, we change `a` to be `12` as well. And if we do `&p`, we get the address of `p` which is an `int **`, a pointer to a pointer to int.

Comment: @user3275095  Yes example show right but notice `a` is an integer variable here not pointer but in your code `char *a` is pointer and you were passing address of pointer .

Comment: @ameyCU Correct. Pointers are hard to learn. When I read it feels that I understood but reality meets when I code. Thank you.